# Codeigniter - load a model in my library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm about to write my own library in codeigniter to check if the logged in user is an admin or not. To do that I need to compare a value with the value of the typeAccount in the DB.
Because I'm still learning the MVC pattern I had a question about this before starting to write my library.
Can I load a model in my library? Or should I communicate directly to my DB in my library? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: ofc you can load your model in libraray

Comment: But I thought that a model can only communicate with a controller, or else it isn't best practice?

Comment: I am using models with controllers. In models I have some function to interact with database and other stuff. Also I made libraray which loads my addons and I made for this libraray special addon.

Comment: Okay thanks for the knowledge transfer :) That is what wasn't clear for me

Comment: Np I'm glad taht I could help you. If you need more help with CI I have skype account where you could write me, so if you want I can send you my details

Comment: That would be really great!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34012/discussion-between-deiform-and-mxx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the library is some kind of logic, you can see it as a piece of the Controller.
The Controller usually just loads a Model to use it.

So yes just load the Model from CodeIgniter instead of connecting to the database yourself.

Makes your code more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can load your model to into your library, simply add CI.

```
class Validator
{
    private $CI = null; 
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function validate_merchantaccount_status($param)
    {
        //Code Here
        $this->CI->load->model('merchantaccount_model');
        $res_merchant = $this->CI->merchantaccount_model->get_list($param);

    }
}
```

Dont forget to make your model.

Comment: or, you could just create a variable. something like $ci =& get_instance(); works too :)

Answer (score -1):

Make you models

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_model extends CI_Model
{
/// Here the code
}
```

And then in controller use

```
$this->load->model('my_model');
```

Ant i think that is best approach :)

Comment: he's asking to load models in libraries. not controllers.

Comment: The same approach is makeing library